# sencha formpanel post data

Tags: forms, post, extjs, upload

i've updated me sencha project to 5.0, i had some code that worked fine in version 4.2.2.
i checked the documentation of extjs 5.0 and the code should still work, can anyone point out what i'm doing wrong here.

```
var formpanel = Ext.getCmp('formpanelUploader');
            formpanel.getForm().submit({
            url: 'SimpleUpload.asp',
            waitMsg: 'Uploading your file......',
            success: function(form, action){ alert('succes'); },
            failure: function(fp, o)
            {   
               console.log('failed!');
            }
```

});

the script in simpleupload.asp hasn't been changed and is still working in me old 4.2.2. project, but in me new 5.0 project it does nothing.

thanks in advance

Comment: your code has errors: "success: function(form, action){ alert('succes'); " - has no closing "}" and the ";" is 100% wrong. Also: using Ext.getCmp is a bad practice and you should avoid it

Comment: thanks for the reply, forgot to set it back i have a succes function lots of code, so i replaced it with alert succes but forgot to put the } back. the code is now right, but still not working.

Comment: Looks fine to me, what errors are you getting? (check the JavaScript console)

Comment: i found the problem, but i don't know how to fix it. the problem is that sencha doesn't post the url to me simpleupload.asp

Comment: zeke, i have no errors in me console log

Comment: take the submit execution into try-catch block and log the possible exception

Comment: i have tried to put it in a try-catch, but it returns no errors. do you know any other solutions  that might work ? thanks in advance.